# How to solve "short write" error when writing to CSV

Tags: multithreading, csv, go

I've been encountering this issue that I can't seem to figure out what's happening. I have code that appends some information to a CSV. The information comes from multiple threads and the CSV is logging times.

At some point during program execution, the code will start spitting out "short write" instead of writing to the CSV.

Printing the data to be outputted, there seems to be no difference in "good" writes and "short" writes and once the "short write" error stops, it continues that until the program is restarted.

This code is called each time a CSV write is desired.

```
        output := []string{time.Message, strconv.FormatInt(time.Duration, 10)}
        fmt.Println(output)
        err := writer.Write(output)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("An error encountered ::", err)
            fmt.Println("writer.Write error")
            logMessage(err.Error())
        }
        writer.Flush()
```

Looking at my output, this is the point where it starts the short write.

```
[message1 21]
[message2 207]
[message3 79]
An error encountered :: short write
writer.Write error
short write
```

And here's my output in the CSV

```
message1,21
message2,207
ssage2,207
```

So it seems like the short write is coming from that second line but why is it writing my message twice, and why is it "short writing" the message? There are hundreds of successful messages then the error just seems to occur suddenly.

Looking at the code, the place to call the CSV writer functionality only hits once, so I'm really stuck on why this is happening.

Comment: The application has a data race on `writer`.  Use a sync.Mutex to ensure that only one goroutine accesses the `writer` at a time.  Run the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) on the application and fix any reported problems.

Comment: Or have one dedicated goroutine that reads from a channel (`chan []string`), writing to the CSV - and all the other goroutines can safely write to this channel without the need for any mutex coordination.

Comment: Thank you! The mutex solved the problem!

Comment: @CeriseLimón Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application has a data race on `writer`. Use a [sync.Mutex](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Mutex) to ensure that only one goroutine accesses the writer at a time.

```go
mu.Lock() // <-- Lock to prevent concurrent write and flush.
output := []string{time.Message, strconv.FormatInt(time.Duration, 10)}
fmt.Println(output)
err := writer.Write(output)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println("An error encountered ::", err)
  fmt.Println("writer.Write error")
  logMessage(err.Error())
}
writer.Flush()
mu.Unlock() // <-- Unlock.
```

Run the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) on the application and fix any reported problems.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using writer with buffer(like `bufio`). This error would happen when a groutine is writing data to buffer and the other is trying to flush.

Just simply add a **locker** in the critical section.

```
mu.Lock()
// critical section
mu.Unlock()
```